# Degrees of freedom for CSS ARMA(2,2) with intercept

Tags: time-series, arima, degrees-of-freedom

This is something I'm been searching for a while now. I'm confused since when you estimate ARMA model by means of conditional sum of squares you are using a special case of maximum likelihood with priors set $
Ma_1,...,Ma_q=E[Ma_1],...,E[Ma_q]=0$ and sum of squares starts from p because we condition the likelihood on the first p points. Here q is number of Ma terms and p is number of Ar terms.

Now, when using R `arima` function with "CSS" option the variance of the residuals is $$\sigma^2=SS/(N-p)$$Shouldn't it be: $$\sigma^2=SS/(N-p-p-q-1)$$, where additionally lost degrees of freedom are due to the $p+q+1$ estimated parameters? In addition, what would you say about calculating p values, are parameters normally or t distributed? Basically are we treating these estimates as maximum likelihood or NLS ones?

Similar questions have been asked but not quite the same.

Comment: I don't think you can estimate an ARMA(p,q) model with q>0 with CSS because the lagged errors are unobservable and so there is no way to form the regressor matrix for least squares.

Comment: I meant non linear least squares which can be estimated with iterative numerical procedures, here we are making it a little easier to optimizer by disregarding some parts of log likelihood which are small in compare to the rest (rest is sum of squares). Also recursion starts with first q lagged errors set to 0.

Comment: OK, I did not now CSS would work like that in `arima`, but it seems it does.